# Creating list and elements with specific id in firebase with angularJS

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm trying to create the following structure in Firebase with its AngularJS API, without any success:
For example, in the https://something.firebaseio.com/

```
+ {element: "node"}        // https://something.firebaseio.com/element
+ {array:                  // https://something.firebaseio.com/array
          {Name1: "element#1"},   // https://something.firebaseio.com/array/Name1
          {Name2: "element#2"}
  }
```

Also, what is the correct method to set/get these values from Firebase?

I'm doing it this way, but it seems wrong:

```
$scope.app = $firebase(new Firebase("https://something.firebaseio.com/"));
$scope.array = app.$child('array');
$scope.array.$push({Name1: "element#1"}); // I know it creates uid in firebase for this object
$scope.app.$set({element: "node"});
```

please let me know in the comments if it's still not clear
thanks,

Comment: Calling $set() will completely overwrite anything you've added with $child().$push(). Does that help?

Comment: so using child() then push() is the right way to create the array/list, how do I get the array into variable to use it ?